# Where is the NSDocumentController in Apple's Document Application Template

Tags: macos, nsdocumentcontroller

Apple makes the point that I will rarely need to subclass NSDocumentController.  OK, but I expected to see it somewhere in the project produced from the document based application template.  Is it in the project, but Apple has "helpfully" hidden it?  Is there something i'm missing there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this link there is a default NSDocumentController:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html .

Other sources indicate that the first document controller created becomes the default.  Presumably, a document controller inited and allocated in the application delegate would become the default and any hidden attempt to create one would happen later and would be ignored.  In this way one could add one's own document controller.

This is probably explicitly explained somewhere, and I missed it.  Sigh!

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a Document-based application, you can find NSDocumentController.h in

Frameworks->AppKit.

The easiest way to find this is to put this line of code

`NSDocumentController* controller;`

Into a .m file, and right-click->Jump To Definition on the `NSDocumentController` part.

Comment: Yes, but lots of things are in AppKit.  Most of them are not included in any app.  I can only assume that NSDocumentController is implicitly inited, allocated, and linked to Document.hm, or to the app, or perhaps to the Menu.

Comment: Then... I don't understand what your question really is.

Comment: I'm asking for an authoritative explanation possibly a confirmation but not necessarily.

Comment: Authoritative explanation of what.